# Is there any way i can optimise the query below?

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by

I have below query in MySQL. It is showing mysql server gone away. What is wrong with the query?

```
SELECT Customer.id,
       Customer.first_name,
       Customer.last_name,
       Sum(Sale.`cal_qty`) AS totPurchase,
       Sale2.tot2          AS totPurchase2
FROM   `customers` AS Customer
       LEFT JOIN `sales` AS Sale
              ON Sale.customer_id = Customer.id
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT s2.customer_id  AS customer_id,
                         Sum(s2.cal_qty) AS tot2
                  FROM   sales AS s2
                  WHERE  s2.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-08-13' AND '2015-09-11'
                  GROUP  BY s2.customer_id) AS Sale2
              ON Sale.customer_id = Sale2.customer_id
WHERE  Sale.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-09-12' AND '2015-10-12'
GROUP  BY Sale.`customer_id`
```

Kindly suggest any optimizations I can do to this query. It have indexed the required columns correctly already.

Comment: Please provide proper DDLs and EXPLAIN for same. Also `LEFT JOIN sale... WHERE sale` is equal to `INNER JOIN sale`, so you might as well write that bit that way to begin with.

Comment: Indexing on customer_id and date. What is need from this sql query. It should give sales of last month and sales of the last to last month against customer_id . need to find whether customer does more than previous month if not then he should not come in to this list after result is fetch.

Comment: Improved English in answer

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Please explain the need for `LEFT`.  If you can't, then get rid of `LEFT`.

Add these indexes:

```
INDEX(sale_date)
INDEX(customer_id, sale_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your WHERE clause is qualifying the SALE table thus turning it into a JOIN vs LEFT JOIN.  Since that is the primary basis of your criteria, I would have that in the lead FROM position as I have adjusted the query (and shortened aliases)

For index optimization, a single index should be on the WHERE AND GROUP by, but also have whatever columns that may be utilized in JOINs.

Sales table... 
index on ( sale_date, customer_id, cal_qty )

This would optimize both the outer AND inner queries for sales activity by date grouped by customer.  Having it a "covering" index that includes the Cal_Qty field prevents the need of going back to the raw data pages for the query.  It can do all it needs from the index components directly.

Customer table should expect to have an index ON (id) as it would be the primary key of that table being joined to.

```
SELECT 
      C.id,
      C.first_name,
      C.last_name,
      Sum(S.cal_qty) AS totPurchase,
      Sale2.tot2 AS totPurchase2
   FROM   
      sales S
         JOIN customers AS C
            ON S.customer_id = C.id
         LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
                           s2.customer_id  AS customer_id,
                           Sum(s2.cal_qty) AS tot2
                        FROM   
                           sales AS s2
                        WHERE  
                           s2.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-08-13' AND '2015-09-11'
                        GROUP BY 
                           s2.customer_id ) AS Sale2
            ON S.customer_id = Sale2.customer_id
   WHERE  
      S.sale_date BETWEEN '2015-09-12' AND '2015-10-12'
   GROUP BY 
      S.customer_id
```